# TestFlight "waiting for review"

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

For my React Native app, I've pushed many builds to TestFlight in the past with no problems. I recently submitted my first actual build to the app store, and now when I'm trying to submit a new build to TestFlight, instead of going into "Testing" mode, it goes into "Waiting for review" and nothing happens. Does anyone know what I should do here? It didn't send out any invites to any of my testers or anything, and it's now been a few hours that it's been hanging in "Waiting for review" mode.

Answer (score 24):

Waiting for review means that apple team will review your app before allowing you to submit on TestFlight for public testing. It will take around 24~48 hours for them to review your app. After if your app is approved, you can submit on TestFlight and create public link for anyone with the link as tester.

Answer (score 11):

Did you increase your application version number? When you deploy to TestFlight the same version number but with a higher build number, it goes directly to `Testing`. However I noticed that changing the version number triggers a new `Waiting for Review` from Apple, before going into `Testing`

Comment: This was a great tip! I had this same issue and with this I just created a new build for an older version to fool the process a bit :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried by uploading same version and change only build number and its got approved immediately.